# functions.https is not a function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy the hello world example from the Google Cloud Docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

I have the required npm packages installed

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Firebase Functions",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^3.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.6.3"
  }
}
```

And my index.js file is the default:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https().onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
})
```

But when I try to deploy:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get the following response:

```
=== Deploying to 'takemyhands-dev'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
i  runtimeconfig: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  runtimeconfig: all necessary APIs are enabled
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: functions.https is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rich\AppData\Local\Temp\fbfn_152524dvCL3dZk176\index.js:6:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\rich\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rich\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:32:3)
```

npm version 5.4.1
node version 6.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it's a typo in the documentation.

Should be:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
})
```

I.e.

function.**https**.onRequest

and not

function.**https()**.onRequest

Comment: *firebaser here* Can you point me to the specific section of the docs where it shows `https()`? I'd love to fix it, but can't find it on the link you gave. All scripts I checked seem to have `functions.https` without parenthesis.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I can't find it now! I definitely copied it rather the type it myself. I think I reached it via the getting started links in the firebase console. Unfortunately, due to using gmail as login, I often have console open incognito and so don't have the page in history. I'll keep an eye out for it though and post here if I find it again.